# Get file from class path so tests can run on all machines

Tags: java, vert.x

I am using Vertx and trying to test some parameters that i am getting data from jsonfile, currently it works but i want get this file just through class path so it can be tested from a different computer.

```
private ConfigRetriever getConfigRetriever() {
    ConfigStoreOptions fileStore = new ConfigStoreOptions().setType("file").setOptional(true)
            .setConfig(new JsonObject()
                .put("path", "/home/user/MyProjects/MicroserviceBoilerPlate/src/test/resources/local_file.json"));
    ConfigStoreOptions sysPropsStore = new ConfigStoreOptions().setType("sys");
    ConfigRetrieverOptions options = new ConfigRetrieverOptions().addStore(fileStore).addStore(sysPropsStore);
    return ConfigRetriever.create(Vertx.vertx(), options);
}
```

My path as written above starts from /home / dir which makes it impossible to be tested on another machine. My test below uses this config

```
@Test
public void tourTypes() {
    ConfigRetriever retriever = getConfigRetriever();

    retriever.getConfig(ar -> {
        if (ar.failed()) {
            // Failed to retrieve the configuration
        } else {
            JsonObject config = ar.result();

            List<String> extractedIds = YubiParserServiceCustomImplTest.getQueryParameters(config, "tourTypes");
            assertEquals(asList("1", "2", "3", "6"), extractedIds);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to make the path a class path so i can test it on all environment.
I tried to access class path like this but not sure how it should be

```
private void fileFinder() {
    Path p1 = Paths.get("/test/resources/local_file.json");
    Path fileName = p1.getFileName();
}
```

Comment: File resourcesFile = new File("src/test/resources/local_file.json");

Comment: how can i add that to my test and still access it because i need a get config , since its a vertx

Comment: You can place it at 'src/test/resources' or 'src/main/resources'

Comment: retriever.getConfig(ar -> {
            if (ar.failed()) {
                // Failed to retrieve the configuration
            } else {
                JsonObject config = ar.result();

Comment: i will not be able to that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have stored the file inside `"src/test/resources"` then you can use

`InputStream confFile = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/local_file.json");`

or

`URL url = getClass().getResource("/local_file.json");`

inside your test class ([example](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2017/01/17/read-file-and-resource-in-junit-test/))

IMPORTANT!
In both cases the file names can start with a / or not. If it does, it starts at the root of the classpath. If not, it starts at the package of the class on which the method is called.

Answer (score 2):

Put .json file to `/resources` folder of your project ([here an example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/)).
Then access it via [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)):

```
InputStream configFile = ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("path/to/file.json");
JsonObject config = new JsonParser().parse(configFile);
// Then provide this config to Vertx
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, considering the location of your json file, you simply need to do this:

```
.setConfig(new JsonObject().put("path", "local_file.json"));
```

See [this](https://gist.github.com/cescoffier/f6f2131d8f1bbdc2320b3c0a2268735d) for reference.